# Como remover elementos colocados pelo django (1.7.5) no template

Tags: django, django-templates

[image: Imagem do projeto atualmente]

Bem eu estou criando o template do meu projeto em django 1.7.5 (tenho motivos para usar essa versão e não posso mudar ) mas o django insiste em colocar essas bolinhas, e como foi gerado pelo django não sei como remover (ainda estou aprendendo )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das formas de resolver isso é usando a propriedade [list style type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp) do `css`. Outra forma é personalizar a saída html do formulário [veja a documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#outputting-forms-as-html).

Comment: O list-style-type não funcionou e eu não sei ao certo o que modificar pela documentação :(